# ImageDataGenerator - trained with model.fit instead of model.fit_generator

Tags: keras, data-augmentation, python-3.x

I am a beginner in using the ImageDataGenerator from Keras and I accidentally used model.fit instead of model.fit_generator.

```
def gen_Image_data():
   gen = ImageDataGenerator(
           width_shift_range=0.1,
           horizontal_flip=True)
   return gen




train_gen = gen_Image_data()
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_samples = train_gen.flow(X,y, batch_size=64)
test_samples = test_gen.flow(X_val, y_val, batch_size=64)

history = model.fit(train_samples, steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(len(X)/64),
              validation_data=(test_samples),
              validation_steps=np.ceil(len(X_val)/64),
              epochs=300, verbose=1, callbacks=[es])
```

Many thanks for every hint

Comment: What's the question? What are you trying to do? Please be more elaborate.

Comment: @Danny I want to do Data Augmentation during training. Has the data been augmented during the training when I only used fit instead of fit_generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data augmentations are defined when you instantiate your data generators. An example is as such:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
```

Other augmentation techniques can also be used by setting the correct parameters. Refer to this link: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: @VicentYong Does that mean that the data has been augmented with my code above and I don't have to train agian using fit_generator instead of just fit?

Comment: The default arguments for ImageDataGenerator based on the link above shows that all the data augmentation techniques are not used if you did not define their parameters. For example, horizontal_flip by default is False. Hene you will need to state which of the techniques you would like to use and provide the necessary parameters.

Comment: @VicentYong ok, I didn't really mean that. I only defined width_shift_range and horizontal_flip in the above code .My question would be whether I am doing data augmentation with  model.fit(....) in the above code or whether it is absolutely necessary to use model.fit_generator(...)?

Comment: It's actually the same as calling fit_generator. Check out line 1130 to 1147 from here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py. If you gave a generator as your parameter in fit method, it will check if its a generator and call fit_generator if it is. And your generator produces the augmented image if you provided the necessary parameters.